# Limiting a subquery before joining in doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello i have the following case:

I want to get the 10 latest posts on my forum, however right now in symfony2 it joins the posts to there corresponding links (because of the websiteid) before limiting it, that way it takes about 250ms to execute a query.

This is my current code:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    "SELECT p, u, t
    FROM MyBundle p
    INNER JOIN p.createdBy u
    INNER JOIN p.thread t
    INNER JOIN t.forum f
    INNER JOIN f.category c
    WHERE c.website = :websiteid
    ORDER BY p.createdOn DESC
");
$query->setParameter('websiteid', $websiteid);
$query->setMaxResults($amount);
$query->setHint(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT, true);

return $query->getResult();
```

This results in as 200ms query and i have no clue on how to optimize it

I tried subquerying but this is very hard in doctrine

any thoughts on this ?

Comment: add a foreign key field to website.id field in the post entity.  That way all you have to do is "Select p from MyBundle p WHERE p.website = :websiteid ORDER BY p.createdOn DESC"

Comment: i removed the inner joins on Forum and Category and i added the website_id FK to thread because i need to show in which thread the post was made, however it still takes 230ms to execute a query

Comment: well inner joins are a bit overkill in this case, so perhaps just using left join should help

Comment: LEFT joins decrease the execution speed to about 250ms

Comment: hmm... perhaps add an index on websiteid in the post entity.  after that, there isn't much else you can do other than perhaps do some really fancy work with virtual tables.

Comment: @MaximGeerinck if you won't select u and t, query might be executed faster, because it will handle lot less columns and if it is file-sorted it means less data to sort. Those values will be lazy-loaded when accessed by direct select by id which should be ok. Another option is little denormalisation and store reference to website in p.

Comment: Yes but if i wanna show let's say 10 records that contains the user on the relationship post, it would then lazy load 10 records resulting in 10 extra queries just to fetch the user

Comment: @MaximGeerinck right, I should mention [eager loading of associations](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) - but I had some problems with more than two levels (user and thread should be okay, forum and category are too deep and it won't load them IIRC) - if needed for more levels, you can simulate it by getting ids you want and loading them by one query for each type

Comment: I used to use eager loading, however in some cases eager loading is not the best solution, that is why i prefer to write the queries out like above, this way i can also cache them more easily

Comment: In that case I can't see many options on doctrine/dql side, you should check generated sql and analyze that (plans, number of rows checked, indexes used). Subquery in FROM is unfortunately not possible  in doctrine. They should be possible in SELECT, but there you can only select one column. Another possibility is to use [Native query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) where really needed, you can use mysql FROM subquery and hydrate entities.